# break Liskov principle with the famous Square/Rectangle example gives a logical error

Tags: c#, properties

I was trying to illustrate the Liskov principle with a case where it breaks it and was expecting in the below example that when you set breadth for the sqaure, the length is automatically set to the same length, and vice versa. 
However, the area is returned as 0. I was expecting 4x4=16, and 5x5=25, in the second case. What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's in the way I'm overriding the properties of the base class.

```
using System;

public class Rectangle
{

    public int length { get; set; }
    public int breadth { get; set; }

    public int area() 
    {
        return length * breadth;
    }

}

public class Square : Rectangle { 


    public new int length;
    public new int breadth;

    public new int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return this.length;
        }
        set
        {
            this.breadth = this.length = value;
        }
    }


    public new int Breadth
    {
        get
        {
            return this.breadth;
        }
        set
        {
            this.breadth = this.length = value;
        }
    }
}


public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        Square s = new Square();
        s.length = 4;
        s.breadth = 5;
        int xx = s.area();
        Console.Write(xx);

        s.length = 5;
        s.breadth = 4;
        xx = s.area();
        Console.Write(xx);

    }



}
```

Comment: Why are you hiding the base class properties?

Comment: how am i hiding them. theyre both public? please explain?

Comment: `new` is not `override` - you're hiding, not overriding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inherit from a `base class`, you will inherit all of its `Public`  and `Protected` members. When you declare a new member in the `derived` class with the same name. The compiler will gives you a warning asking you are you intended to hide that member? When you used the `new` keyword you told the compiler: Yes I want to hide this member please. The implementation of the `area` Method uses the `base` class `properties`, so it will not see your public `Fields` That's why you get the `0`.
So your code will become:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    protected int _length;
    protected int _breadth;
    public virtual int Length
    {
        get { return _length; }
        set { _length = value; }
    }
    public virtual int Breadth {
        get { return _breadth; }
        set { _breadth = value; }
    }

    public int Area()
    {
        return Length * Breadth;
    }

}

public class Square : Rectangle
{

    public override int Breadth
    {
        get { return _breadth; }
        set { _breadth = value;
            _length = _breadth;
        }
    }
    public override int Length {
        get { return _length; }
        set { _length = value;
            _breadth = _length;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to `override` something, you should add the `virtual` keyword in the `base` class definition of that `thing`.
In your example, you will cause a `StackOverFlow` exception. Because each property setters will call the other. That's why I used a protected member to prevent this thing from happening. 
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) is a good reference for you to read about inheritance

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud it worked with virtual - override.

Comment: You're welcome, I would like to ask who down vote to tell me what he think is wrong with this answer?

Comment: @Mahmoud I'm not the downvoter so I can only guess. My guess would be that your example doesn't show how to correctly do this - it actually shows it the same way how the question is. I'd definitely update the example to show how to correctly do this.

Comment: Thank you, I focused on the `new`ing. I will edit this answer.